# React Native local image loads a second after content

Tags: react-native

I have a local image that I am using as a background image. It loads around a second after the rest of the content.

```
<Image source={require('./assets/climbing_mountain.jpeg')} style={styles.imageContainer}>  

imageContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  width: null,
  height: null,
}
```

Is there a way to load the content after the image is loaded? I tried using the [onLoad](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.32/docs/image.html#onload) and [onLoadEnd](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.32/docs/image.html#onloadend) props, but they were fired prior to the image loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.. it's not that simple actually, you will need to use Image prefetch.. check this link : [React Image prefetch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#examples)

Or actually you can try this:

```
    <Image
     onLoadEnd={()=>this.setState({loadEnd:true})}
     source={require('./assets/climbing_mountain.jpeg')}
     style={styles.imageContainer}>
```

and in the render method you can do something like which I don't really recommend:

```
render(){
  if(!this.state.loadEnd) {
    return(
        <Image
         key='image_key'
         onLoadEnd={()=>this.setState({loadEnd:true})}
         source={require('./assets/climbing_mountain.jpeg')}
         style={styles.imageContainer}> 
    )
  }else {
    return (
      <View>
        ....
        <Image
         key='image_key'
         onLoadEnd={()=>this.setState({loadEnd:true})}
         source={require('./assets/climbing_mountain.jpeg')}
         style={styles.imageContainer}> 
        </view>
        ....
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @challenger! I implemented your second method, but as you said it's not ideal, so I'll give the other way a shot.

Comment: The prefetch is not a valid solution in this case, because it only works for remote images.